# I am not able to display the heading and the navbar on the same line.How do i do it?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to learn html and css by making a portfolio website and encountered this problem.I want to place the heading and the navbar along the same line.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 80px;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.navbar {
  list-style: none;
  right: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
}

.navbar li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section class="header">Prashanth Sateesh

  <ul class="navbar">
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Tech Skills</li>
    <li>Guest book</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed some extra code for the sake of the example but you need to use `display: inline-block;` You also had a lot of extra rules that weren't necessary. Such as absolute positioning on the `.header` as well as two `height` rules. You can add things back in like the `font-size` and such. I only removed them so this example is more clear.

*EDIT: Updated for comment below*

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}

#wrapper{
   background-color:#DCDCDC;
   font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
   text-align: right;
}

.header{
   display:inline-block;
}

.navbar{
   list-style:none;
   display:inline-block;
}

.navbar li{
   display:inline-block;
   padding-right:20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="header">Prashanth Sateesh</div>

  <ul class="navbar">
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Tech Skills</li>
      <li>Guest book</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks.can you also tell me how to move the navbar to the right of the page.i made some small changes now like i added a div for making the entire header bacground color #dcdcdc

Comment: Check my update but you should start a new question if you are going to need more help beyond this original question.

Answer (score 1):

See [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/Indirpendent/pen/gRGgxr)

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    <title>Prashanth Sateesh</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="bar">
      <section class="header">
        Prashanth Sateesh
        <ul class="navbar">
          <li>About</li>
          <li>Tech Skills</li>
          <li>Guest book</li>
          <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.bar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
  padding: 20px 80px;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.header {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
}


.navbar li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 20px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.header{
   height:30px;
   background-color:#DCDCDC;
   height:50px;
   display:inline-block; /* inline-block does the trick */
   padding-top:20px;
   padding-left:80px;
   font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
   font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

Comment: It didnt work now the background color surrounds only the heading prashanth sateesh

Comment: you need to set background color on a parent div so !

Comment: @PooyaRaki So why don't you put a style for parent div into your answer?

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph I know you know how to do it ! The op has the style already but need to define a parent !